# jPanelMenu runs and creates an extra <div class="jPanelMenu-panel">

Tags: jquery, jpanel

I'm attempting to implement [**jPanelMenu**](http://jpanelmenu.com) on my site but after menu is triggered there is extra space between the jPanelMenu-menu and jPanelMenu-panel.
I checked it out with Firebug and when

```
`<body data-menu-position="open">`
```

an extra jPanelMenu-panel div appears like this

```
`<div class="jPanelMenu-panel" style="position: relative; left: 250px;">
     <div class="jPanelMenu-panel" style="position: relative; left: 250px;">
           ...
     </div>
 </div>`
```

I don't understand why this is happening so if anyone has an idea or any feedback please let me know :)

[Here's the full code on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lfowler1290/Tt5aU/)

THANKS in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jPanelMenu creates the extra divs. You should not have any elements with the `jPanelMenu-menu` ID or `jPanelMenu` class outside of what the code automatically creates.

> When jPanelMenu is turned on, two `<div>` elements are created. The menu element (with an ID of `jPanelMenu-menu`), and the panel element (with a class of `jPanelMenu-panel`). In addition, a class of `jPanelMenu` is applied to the `<html>` tag.

See the [documentation](http://jpanelmenu.com/index.html#inner-workings) for more information.

Additionally, make sure the JavaScript is only running once the DOM is ready.

Here is an example that should help you get started: http://jsfiddle.net/Cxh6p/

Comment: Thanks, Cory! Looking over your comments and changes I understand my mistakes. Any idea how to work this into wordpress?

Comment: No idea, that's outside of my area of expertise. Try asking about integrating jPanelMenu on the [Wordpress StackExchange site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Additional tips: If you're trying to use em units (for responsive design or otherwise) you should try to avoid mixing them with px units by [converting px to em](http://pxtoem.com/). There's a lot of good articles on why and how to use ems, so go check them out - they behave a little differently than px. Also, make sure those gradients are cross-browser compatible. The [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator site](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) will help you generate the CSS for them. Hope this helps. :0)

Comment: Oh, and bonus points if you look up embedded typography/fonts. You can convert the title image into text with an embedded font (so it also scales properly) and use [an embedded icon font](http://css-tricks.com/examples/IconFont/) for the menu trigger.